# Palindrome strings comparison in a list using a function

Tags: python

Hi i have got a list of items in strings in a list. I want see if these words in strings are palindromes using a function.
So far i have got this code,

```
input_list = ['taco cat', 'bob', 'davey']
def palindromes(x):
    for x in input_list:
        if x == x[::-1]
            return True
        else:
            return False 
output = [palindromes(x)]
print(output)
```

the result should be in a list [ True, True, False ]
what am i doing wrong here plz?

Comment: Is `taco cat` really the same as the string reversed? the answer is no, because of the space in middle. So you have to improve your function to stripe white spaces before the comparison.

Comment: Again: You are in my class; this is a class exercise. You can ask me. You have not asked me.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably simplify the `palindromes` function to just handle a single string:

```
def palindrome(x):
    x = x.replace(" ", "")  # given your sample data
    return x == x[::-1]
```

And then use a comprehension:

```
output = [palindrome(x) for x in input_list]
```

Or, using `map`:

```
output = [*map(palindrome, input_list)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
input_list = ['taco cat', 'bob', 'davey']
def palindromes(x):
   x_no_spaces = x.replace(' ', '')
   return x_no_spaces == x_no_spaces[::-1]

print([palindromes(i) for i in input_list]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```py
input_list = ['taco cat', 'bob', 'davey']


def palindromes(x):
    return x == x[::-1]


output = [palindromes(x) for x in input_list]
print(output)
```

```py
[False, True, False]
```

Comment: It would be better to use a `palindrome` function that would process just one entry.